# Open source Automation Tools for html based calendar software

Tags: automated-testing

I am testing an appointment based software, where clients book appointments on a calendar. When you login to the site, calendar will be loaded with a weekly view displaying appointments. For everyday slots will be from 12AM to 11.59 PM. Each hour will be divided into 4 parts. When you click on a slot, popup will open where you need to enter appointment details and save it. This is the overview of the project. What would be the suitable opensource tool for it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the application is based on flash, html, silverlight, or other stuff?

Comment: application is based on html

Comment: Hmmm... there was a very similar question a few days ago. May I ask you to make a little research to find that one. There you can find answers which testing framework can deal with HTML stuff. To be honest, I would use WebDriver.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [Selenium Web driver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).